# Will the @Validated annotation in the DAO Interface help at all?

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, interface, dao

I have seen a lot of [`@Validated`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html) annotations in the DAOs interface that I didn't write. For example:

```
@Validated
public interface CompanyDAO extends BaseDAO<Company> {

    public List<Company> list();
```

What behaviour should I expect from this:

- Validating all the objects passed to the DAO before saving them into the database?
- Validating all the objects that the DAO retrieves from the database?
- Both of them?
- Nothing at all. This annotation should not be placed in DAO interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few pointers which you might not be aware of:

- [8.8 Spring Validation of 8. Validation, Data Binding, and Type Conversion in the manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation) specifies that

  > In order to be eligible for Spring-driven method validation, all target classes need to be annotated with Spring’s `@Validated` annotation, optionally declaring the validation groups to use. Check out the `MethodValidationPostProcessor` javadocs for setup details with Hibernate Validator and Bean Validation 1.1 providers.
- [`MethodValidationPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/MethodValidationPostProcessor.html) says

  > Applicable methods have JSR-303 constraint annotations on their parameters and/or on their return value (in the latter case specified at the method level, typically as inline annotation), e.g.:

  ```
  public @NotNull Object myValidMethod(@NotNull String arg1, @Max(10) int arg2)
  ```

  > Target classes with such annotated methods need to be annotated with Spring's Validated annotation at the type level, for their methods to be searched for inline constraint annotations. Validation groups can be specified through `@Validated` as well. By default, JSR-303 will validate against its default group only.

So, maybe the answer to your question

> What behaviour should I expect

is: Whatever constraints are given in the code.